# Getting the name of a row which is grouped

Tags: r, dplyr

[image]I want to get the name of the region which has the highest average change from a given csv file "life.expectancy". I used the "dplyr" package for this, however, when I try to retrieve the name of the region at the final step I get the error:
Error in lapply(.x, .f, ...) : object 'average.change' not found. Is there a way I can get the name of the region which corresponds to the maximum change?

EDIT: I replaced max(average.change) with max(grouped.by.region$average.change) and have added the output. I only want "South Asia", a value, as an output though.

[image]

```
grouped.by.region <- life.expectancy %>%
  group_by(region) %>%
  summarise(average.change = mean(change)
  )

region.max.change <- grouped.by.region[grouped.by.region$average.change == 
                                       max(average.change), "region"]
```

Comment: Please provide a data example, e.g. by using `dput(head(life.expectancy))`.

Comment: I have added a snippet of how the data looks like.

Comment: `grouped.by.region$region[which.max(grouped.by.region$average.change)]`

Answer (score 2):

In `max(average.change)` R wants to know the data.frame of `average.change`again and you should do `max(grouped.by.region$average.change)`.

```
region.max.change <- grouped.by.region[grouped.by.region$average.change == 
                                       max(grouped.by.region$average.change), "region"]
```

Output the value as character:

```
as.character(region.max.change)
# [1] "South Asia"
```

Comment: I tried the below line, and it returns me a set of True and False values instead

Comment: Tried it with other data, just corrected my code.

Comment: Thank you! I have made an edit with the output I got.

Comment: I've extended my answer accordingly. Would this work for you?

Comment: just `grouped.by.region$region[which.max(grouped.by.region$average‌​.change)]` would do

Comment: Both the solutions worked, thank you!

Comment: @The_ Bolt Very good -- and in that case it is customary to 'accept an answer' (click on the check mark you see next to it) as well as to 'upvote' it (click on the upward-facing triangle). You can vote on any question, you can accept only questions you asked.